# What is the mode of the convoluted probability density function?

Tags: random-variable, convolution, mode

If I am aware of the distributions of both $V$ and $U$, is there general guiding principle in terms of the position of the mode of the distribution of $\varepsilon =V-U$.

As I am not specifying the exact distributions, I am not looking for a closed-form solution. I am just wondering if there are things or rules that would help me to determine if the mode of $\varepsilon$ is on the left or right to the mode of $V$, etc.

Comment: As a general proposition, the answer is no.  Consider exploring some simple cases, such as sums of Normal and Bernoulli variables, to see for yourself.  Would you be able to narrow the focus of your question to specific distributions or some characteristic statistical problem?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I guess I can solve it by deriving it myself. I am thinking normal V with Half normal U or exponential U. I thought there must be some small theorems that talks about this but it’s good to know that there is none.